# Python ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'

Tags: python, object, python-imaging-library, detection

Below code is part of my code

```
import time
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False

import mmcv
from mmcv.runner import load_checkpoint
import mmcv.visualization.image as mmcv_image


def imshow(img, win_name='', wait_time=0): plt.figure(
    figsize=(50, 50)); plt.imshow(img)


mmcv_image.imshow = imshow
from mmdet.models import build_detector
from mmdet.apis import inference_detector, show_result, init_detector
```

and this part has an error

```
from mmcv.runner import load_checkpoint
```

error is like below

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps, ImageEnhance, __version__ as PILLOW_VERSION
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__'
```

but I have already executed pip install Pillow, please is anyone could help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to version issues as discussed in [this Github issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4130)

Can you try the following?

`pip install Pillow==6.1`

Also, removing and reinstalling Pillow might help.

Comment: Really thanks for your help. Pillow 6.1 version works. My original version is 7.0